# Running NodeJS Application in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am making an electron application,

I have made a node application working on localhost:3000 using express. I want that application to work in electron.

How will i do that?

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/assets')));
app.use('/data', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/data')));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/bower_components')));
app.listen(3000);
```

Now i want a sort of a build for this in a folder, where i can navigate the URL of mainWindow in Electron. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Why would you want to run a server inside of a client application?

Comment: I want the offline version of this in Electron !! I don't know how to do that. Can you give me any suggestion?

Comment: So you want to make your app work offline (when the real Node.js Express server is not available)?

Comment: Each time i want to run the application, i go to terminal and do the npm start, then i load the URL in electron, 'http://localhost:4000'. I just want either the electron runs the server itself or my node Application goes in Build mode in a folder and i navigate the Electron Url to that folder. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to build for development or for shipping?

Comment: Shipping. Can you help me with it?